# Reading one sheet from excel in rstudio

Tags: r, excel, import, readfile

I have an excel file with two sheets, A & B.
I need to upload and use the data in Rstudio from **sheet B ONLY.**
How can I do that?

I imported the file to the rstudio and I wrote this :
`dat <- read_excel ("multi_anova.xlsx")`

but when I try to use the data, such as `(dat$id)` , it gives me all the excels's file id's, not only the B sheet.

How can I get the B sheet's ids ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the sheet name from where you want to read the data in `read_excel` function -

```
dat <- read_excel("multi_anova.xlsx", sheet = "B")
dat$id
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.xlsx` from `openxlsx`

```
library(openxlsx)
dat <- read.xlsx("multi_anova.xlsx", sheet = "B")
dat$id
```